# What is someone called who incurs expenses?

Tags: nouns

What do you call a person who incurs expenses? Is there a specific word in English?

Comment: In accountancy he would probably be a *cost centre* or part of a cost centre. But that doesn't help much. I suppose you could call him a *spender*.

Comment: A _liability_...

Comment: I'm tempted to say "my wife", but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: @WS2 An 'overhead'?

Comment: @Christopher In accountant's jargon, an 'overhead' is only one category of expense. There are others.

Answer (score 1):

I think  the word you may be looking for is,

[Spender](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spender):

> - a person who spends, especially one who habitually spends excessively or lavishly; spendthrift.

Comment: No! The person paying could well be different to the person *incurring* the expense, and often is.

Comment: The other possibility is SPENDER:a person who spends, especially one who habitually spends excessively.

Comment: What if he isn't particularly spending excessively?

Comment: A moderate spender!!

Answer (score 1):

Why not *[payer](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=payer)*?

> One named responsible for paying a bill or note. *American Heritage*

Similar, but more formal sounding is *[remunerator](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remunerator)*.  *Merriam-Webster* defines *remunerate* as

> to pay an equivalent to for a service, loss, or expense

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you're going for "creditor"/"obligee" -- who pays for something on your behalf and whom you now owe (you're the "debtor"/obligor").  This could be, for example, your credit card company, or "Joe, buy me those M&Ms and I'll pay you back".  Not sure if this is the sense you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to such a person as a *backer" - * i.e., it is their money that is being spent.

Colloquially, there is also the expression "Sugar Daddy" (or "Mama) for an older person who takes on all the expenses of a younger lover. This can also sometimes be used figuratively (although it's kind of disrespectful) in business.

Answer (score 0):

The right word I was looking for is:

> expender - someone who spends money to purchase goods or services [(Click here for reference)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expender)